# How to update the values of `route_ids` through Web API in the `product.template` in Odoo/OpenERP 8?

Tags: postgresql, odoo, xml-rpc, openerp-8

After connecting to the server using `xmlrpc` and following the instructions from [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html), I try to change the value of the `route_ids` (*Procurement -> Supply Chain Information -> Routes*) so none of the three options (*Manufacture, Buy, Make To Order*) is selected.

First I take the current values:

```
>>> models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
...     'product.template', 'read',
...     [125], {'fields': ['route_ids']})
{'route_ids': [5, 6, 1], 'id': 125}
```

Then I attempt to update the values:

```
>>> models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'product.template', 'write', 
...     [[125], {'route_ids': []}])    
True
```

And finally I check whether the values have been updated or not:

```
>>> models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
...     'product.template', 'read',
...     [125], {'fields': ['route_ids']})
{'route_ids': [5, 6, 1], 'id': 125}
```

Any idea why this does not work? I got the same results, i.e. no change, when I tried to change the `display_name` but when I tried to change the `weight_net` everything works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a look at the documentation about the write method [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.models.Model.write), you would understand why it is not working.
Actually the page you gave does reference it explicitly, [there](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html#create-records).

So I think that the problem you're having is that you are trying to empty the route_ids, assigning to it an empty list.

The documentation states:

> One2many and Many2many use a special “commands” format to manipulate the set of records stored in/associated with the field.
>
> This format is a list of triplets executed sequentially, where each triplet is a command to execute on the set of records. Not all commands apply in all situations.

The one we are interested in to delete the records:

> (5, _, _)
>
> removes all records from the set, equivalent to using the command 3 on every record explicitly. Can not be used on One2many. Can not be used in create().

So I think you should write instead:

```
>>> models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'product.template', 
                        'write', [[125], {'route_ids': [[5, 0, 0]]}])    
True
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. There is a slight syntax error in your answer though. In order to delete all the entries:
`models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'product.template', 'write', [[id], {'route_ids': [(5, 0, 0)]}])`
In order to add one entry, e.g. with id "1":
`models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'product.template', 'write', [[id], {'route_ids': [(4, 1, 0)]}])`

Comment: Actually I don't really see a difference between my answer and your comment. Well you use a tuple instead of a list to pass the (5, 0, 0), but in my experience both work the same.

Comment: nvm, that's the only difference and indeed I just checked with list instead of the tuple and it also works.